# wordpress flat theme sidebar from left to right

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

I'm using flat theme from http://www.yoarts.com/wordpress/free-flat-design-wordpress-theme.html.
I tried editing style.css :

```
#page:before, .sidebar-offcanvas, #secondary  {float: right !important;}
```

But take only partial of the sidebar and not the continue sidebar / whole sidebar to the right.
any solution I should do?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your css:

```
#page::before{
    right:0;
}
```

And your sidebar will float to the right.